# git push origin masterでエラーになる

Tags: git

タイトルの通りgit push origin masterでエラーになります
いろいろググって対処法を試してみたのですがよくわかりませんでした
以下のようなエラーがでます

```
C:\Users\purius\Desktop\RailsSite>git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/1ds11097s/RailsSite.git'
```

ちなみにばりばりの初心者です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git init`した後、変更を1つもコミットせずに`git push`しようとするとこのエラーが出ることがあります。

`git add`と`git commit`を使ってREADMEや.gitignoreなど何か1つコミットをしてください。

（追伸： `git push origin master` のかわりに `git push --set-upstream origin master` または省略形の `git push -u origin master` とすると、以後 `git push` と打つだけで origin の master に push されます）

Comment: 試しに、Gemfileを使ってやってみたところ

Comment: C:\Users\purius\Desktop\RailsSite>git add Gemfile


C:\Users\purius\Desktop\RailsSite>git commit

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'purius@purius-PC.(none)')

とでました。
その後、git push origin masterをしたところまた同じエラーが出ました

Comment: @user20519 `git commit`の時点でエラーが出ており、コミットできていません。対処法はエラーメッセージの中に書いてあります。そのエラーメッセージをコピペしてググってみてください。`git config --global`を使ってユーザー設定をしないといけないはずです。

Comment: ユーザー設定をしたところ上手くできました！
本当に助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @user20519 よろしければ[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)していただけると嬉しいです :)